# How to use JavaScript in Django html file for error messages?

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates, sweetalert

In my html template have error messages for form validation like below:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <span class="text-danger small">{{ field.errors }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

If I want to use sweet alert for that how can I do it

If I use like below it will give a empty alert when page loads but when the error happens it will give an empty alert like the when pages loading how can I pass those data into sweet alert what did I do wrong?

```
{% for field in form %}
    <span class="text-danger small">{{ field.errors }}</span>
    <script>
      var a = "{{ field.errors }}"
      swal(a)
    </script>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: if i use a ``console.log.(a)`` it will give an error like below in console  ``Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier``

Comment: result will be like ``var a = "<ul class="errorlist"><li>Enter a valid email address.</li></ul>"`` so how can i access this with correct way

Answer (score 1):

Error has occurred because the error message with double quotes is enclosed within double quotes.

You can either enclose it in template literal or single quotes to execute without error.

```js
var a = `<ul class="errorlist"><li>Enter a valid email address.</li></ul>`;
console.log(a);
```

Comment: can you tell me a way to get ``Enter a valid email address.`` just results as ``var a``

Comment: You can pass the html itself directly to sweet alert. 
`Swal.fire({
  title: '<strong>Errors</strong>',
  type: 'info',
  html: '<ul class="errorlist"><li>Enter a valid email address.</li></ul>'
});`

Comment: If you want only text without html, then you can loop each error from errors and push it to a js array and use it. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694489/django-form-errors-get-the-error-without-any-html-tags)

Answer (score 0):

Form errors are provided by form.errors in django so, insert error in dict errordict={} and return errordict to template

In views.py

```
errodict={} 
   for f in form.errors:
             self.errordict[f] = '.'.join(form.errors[f])
```

In template

```
 {% if errodict %}
                            <script>
                            var r="{{ errodict }}";
                            alert('error:'+r)
                            </script>
                            {{ errodict}}
      {% endif %}
```