How to get form file data rendered in form invalid cases in django
i have defined a form in django as :
forms.py
 @parsleyfy
 class CreationForm(forms.Form):
     sample_name=forms.CharField(label="Agent Name",max_length=40, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'maxlength': '40', 'placeholder':""}),error_messages={'error-message': "Enter valid Name",'required':'Please Enter Name'})
     sample_description=forms.CharField(label="agent description",max_length=100,widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'maxlength': '40', 'placeholder':""}),error_messages={'error-message': "Enter valid  Description",'required':'Please Enter Description'})
     logo=forms.FileField(label="Logo",error_messages={'error-message': "Please Upload Valid File",'required':'Please Upload Logo'})
     def __init__(self,request,*args, **kwargs):
        if request:
            self.request=request
        kwargs.setdefault('label_suffix', '')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

I am using classbased views:
Views.py:
 class CreationView(FormView):
     template_name = 'creation.html'
     form_class = CreationForm
     def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
         try:
             return super(CreationView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
         except Exception as e:
             print("Exception in dispatch of CreationView form",e)
     def get_initial(self):
         init = super(CreationView, self).get_initial()
         init.update({'request':self.request})
         return init
     def get_form_kwargs(self):
         kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
         kwargs['request'] = self.request
         return kwargs
     def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):   
         context = super(CreationView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
         form_class = self.get_form_class()
         context['form']=self.get_form(form_class)
         return context
     def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         try:
             print(self.request.POST,"POST Request")
             print(self.request.FILES,"files in the request")
             form_class = self.get_form_class()
             form = self.get_form(form_class)
             if form.is_valid():
                return self.form_valid(form, **kwargs)
             else:
                print("inside form invalid")
                return self.form_invalid(form, **kwargs)
         except Exception as e:
             print("Exception in creationview",e)
     def form_valid(self, form):
         print("inside form valid")
         return render(self.request,'creation.html',{'form':form})
    
     def form_invalid(self,form):
         return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))

creation.html:
   <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
     {{ field }}
     {{ field.label_tag }}
     {% for error in field.errors %}
        <div class="error">
           {{ error }}
         </div>
     {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

whenever form is invalid (eg: name is invalid, i am throwing error as "Invalid Name" with form to the same html again. but the uploaded file is not getting along with form data.
How can i handle this scenario in form invalid cases.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694489/django-form-errors-get-the-error-without-any-html-tags see this..!

@Tanveer i am able to render the Error messages to html. the exact issue is how to handle File Upload  in form invalid cases?

you can't ! the file field will always return empty due to security issues, please see this post for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205634/restoring-the-value-of-a-input-type-file-after-failed-validation

another post on the same question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967916/how-to-keep-input-type-file-field-value-after-failed-validation-in-asp-net-mvc?rq=3
